# Angular ui-grid doesn't update view after data arrived from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Maybe this question was asked before, but i tried the solutions i saw in other posts such as disabling the fast watch, but nothing seems to work...

I have a grid using Angular ui-grid in my web page and the behavior i'm seeking for is that after click on a button the data must be updated. The issue is i can see that gridOptions.data is updated, the columnDefs too, even the length but view doesn't update, also the displaying becomes a bit messy and i have to scroll to get it right.

Here's my code

Controller :

```
(function(app) {



'use strict';



app.controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);



function Ctrl($scope, $routeSegment, $log, $filter) {

$log.debug('Controller - init()');

// Set ViewModel Object - will be exported in View
var viewModel = this;


viewModel.gridOptionsData = [];
viewModel.gridOptions = {};
viewModel.gridOptions.paginationPageSizes = [25, 50, 75];
viewModel.gridOptions.paginationPageSize = 25;
viewModel.gridOptions.data = [];
viewModel.gridOptions.rowIdentity = function(row) {
  return row.id;
};
viewModel.gridOptions.getRowIdentity = function(row) {
  return row.id;
};


$scope.showgrid = false;
$scope.filterText;

viewModel.refreshData = function() {
  viewModel.gridOptions.data = $filter('filter')(viewModel.gridOptionsData, $scope.filterText, undefined);
};

$scope.$watch('dataStructure', function(data) {
  if (angular.isDefined(data) && !angular.equals(data, [])) {
    var struct = [];
    for (var key in data[0]) {
      if (angular.equals(key, 'id')) {
        struct.push({
          field: key, 
          visible : false
        });
      } else {
        struct.push({
          field: key, 
        });
      }
    }
    viewModel.gridOptionsData = data;
    viewModel.gridOptions.data = data;
    viewModel.gridOptions.columnDefs = struct;
    $scope.showgrid = true;
  }
});
  }

}(angular.module('app')));
```

View :

```
<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="pageViewModel.gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ></div>
              <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.filterText" ng-change="pageViewModel.refreshData()" placeholder="Search / Filter" />
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: In `$scope.$watch('dataStructure',...)`, where is `dataStructure` defined?

Comment: it is binded to $scope... I solved the problem by supressing rowIdentity and getRowIdentity functions